# Inconsistency when dividing long values in Java

Tags: java, timestamp, overflow, long-integer

I know this will seem insane, I have been scratching my head over it right now and am pretty sure there is something I am missing.

I am calculating the 'countOfMinutes' that have occurred since that start of the day compared to the currentTime. To do that I am doing the below:

```
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Below mod function gets code to start of the day
    long lastStart = startTime - (startTime % (TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)));

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long minuteInMs = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1);
    countOfMinutes = (now - lastStart) / minuteInMs;
```

This is a snippet of the code that I have running 24/7 and gets periodically restarted. I have logs from the output where I log the 'lastStart' value, the 'now' value, and the 'countOfMinutes'. I used those same values on my localmachine and I get expected values. But when looking at the logs, those same values lead to 0. I can't understand why the same numbers would lead to different values.

Here are the logs that I have from the system running:

```
18:21:53.908 INFO  [Thread-3] Adjusted start time= 1550102400000\n
18:21:53.908 INFO  [Thread-3] Current time= 1550168520001\n
18:21:53.908 INFO  [Thread-3] countOfMinutes based on start time= 0\n
```

So I took those values and ran locally and got what I would expect:

```
14:52:17.037 [main] INFO  The difference is:66120001
14:52:17.041 [main] INFO  value of countOfMinutes:1102
```

I was thinking something with overflow, but just not sure how its possible this could happen some of the time. I don't suspect logs could get corrupt like this and toString() method of long shows one thing when its actually another.

Edited: Updating with actual code
NOTE: The actual code already has things I identify that should be updated. e.g. logging lastStart instead of startTime if thats what I am going to be using in the calculation, storing now and then logging now rather than calling System.currentTime multiple times, and others. I suppose with the discrepancy in what's getting logged vs. actual variable values (which we don't know) it could lead to this, but it seems odd it would.
Below is code:

```
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long lastStart = startTime - (startTime % (TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)));
    startTime = lastStart;

    logger.info("Adjusted start time= {}", startTime); // Adjust start time to start of the day

    long minuteInMs = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1);
    logger.info("Current time= {}", System.currentTimeMillis());

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long countOfMinutes = (now - lastStart) / minuteInMs;

    logger.info("countOfMinutes based on start time= {}", countOfMinutes);
```

Comment: The error is clearly in the logging, then.

Comment: The logging is accurate in that there is followup code that happens when its this 0 value, and I can see those lines getting executed over and over until it gets to the proper count. So it is actually 0. The error in logging might be in currentTime or startTime though, but doesn't seem likely. This happens randomly, couple times a week so its more than an anomaly

Comment: have you wrapped them with "Synchronized" ?

Comment: It's possible you get an overflow if you aren't careful during the logging and `(now - lastStart)` turns into an `int` and it all gets rounded down to `0` with the division.

Comment: @SivarajVelayutham Not synchronized, but the long's are declared as volatile

Comment: The problem is not overflow in division.  Dividing a large number by a small number will not cause overflow.

Comment: @Kirit Wrap them with synchronized and remove the volatile. Because, your logic to calculate the countOfMinutes is within the Thread memory. Volatile Variables are stored in directly in main memory of your system and can be accessed by multiple threads.

Comment: You need to show us the actual code that is causing this, including the actual code that is writing the log messages.  Also, I assume that you have checked / double checked that the code you are running in production matches the source code that you are looking at (!)

Comment: What is the type of `countOfMinutes`?

Comment: Re - Sivaraj's comment.  *"... and can be accessed by multiple threads"*.  They could be accessed **and updated** by multiple threads ... leading to race conditions.

Comment: It’s weird. Your calculation should give the minutes since start of day *in UTC*, but you know that. Another observation: Your calculated 1102 minutes should correspond to 18:22, but the numbers are logged already 18:21:53.908 (corresponing to only 1101 minutes).

Comment: Have I understood correctly that in the systemrunning this often works as expected and the unexpected 0 comes sporadically?